# How get the json file path in swift framework and get the data from it?

Tags: ios, json, swift, frameworks, nsbundle

Am new to using the JSON for parsing the data and use it in Swift framework and after computation send it to application for display purposes.

I tried the following code to open a Json file and read it but am always ending up with the "Invalid  file Path" due to nil return into the path.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("furnitures", ofType: "json") {
    print(path)

    do {
        let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        do {
            let jsonResultDict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            if let furnTyp : [NSDictionary] = jsonResultDict["furnTypes"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                for furType: NSDictionary in furnTyp {
                    for (name,value) in furType {
                        if name as! String == "sofa" {
                            print(value)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            "exception at NSJSONSerialization"
        }
    } catch {
        print("exception at NSData")
    }
}
else {
    print("Invalid  file Path")
}
```

Also i tried the following code to get the path and passed it to NSData to get the contents of the file and ended up with exception at NSData

```
let file = "furnitures.json"
var jsonFilePath: String! = nil
if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
    //path will be stored here
    jsonFilePath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    print(jsonFilePath) //  printing the file path          
}
```

so kindly help me out on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Anupam Mishra for editing my post